# How can I write this statement so it stays as an ActiveRecord call?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

I'm trying to make a query that, I believe, is a double joins call.

```
@customer.jobs.joins(:assignments).where('assignments.employee_id' => current_user.id).collect{|j|j.payments}.flatten
```

I'm looking for payments, only if they've been assigned to my current_user under my customer record.

Payments are connected to customers through a joins table ( `payment_applications` ). Employees are assigned to Jobs through a join table ( `assignments` ).

The query above returns the right objects, but its an array so I can't assign them to pagination. How can I keep that query an ActiveRecord call?

Comment: What do you use for pagination? Kaminari allows pagination of arrays: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object , are you sure your paginating tool only works on relations?

Comment: What do your models look like for customer, payment, user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to end up with Payments, I recommend starting your query there:

```
@payments = Payment.for_customer(customer)
```

And in your model:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_user(user)
    joins(:assignments).where('assignments.employee_id' => user.id)
  end
end
```

And if you want to join the customer record, change to

```
joins(:assignments => :customers)
```

Comment: Payments are not associated with assignments. Payments are associated with payment_applications which is a joins table connecting payments to jobs. Jobs are connected to Employees by `assignments`.

Comment: payments => payment_applications => jobs ( there can be many jobs ) => assignments => employees ( there can be many employees )

Comment: soooo change it to joins(:payments => :payment_applications => :jobs => :assignments => :employees)

Comment: I guess I just don't know how to write that syntactically. :D

Comment: but I just did it for you.

Comment: for more information, check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html 11.2.4 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

Comment: Payment.joins(:payment_applications => :jobs => :assignments => :employees) returns : `SyntaxError: unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
...ayment_applications => :jobs => :assignments => :employees)`

Comment: And your answer returns `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3fc7c7386390>`